# Why can't I remove columns/props from select in linq statement

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I want to remove columns which I don't need to display!

Basically customer needs to see only **FirstName** and **LastName**, so I wanted to return only **FirstName** and **LastName** to end user.

But my app breaks If I remove other props from select:

```
  var product = await _context.Products.OrderBy(p => p.CreatedDate)
                .Select(x => new Product
                {
                    ProductId = x.ProductId,
                    GroupId = x.GroupId,
                    ProductStatus = x.ProductStatus,
                    Title = x.Title,
                    Price = x.Price
                }).FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.ProductId == dbObj.Id && u.GroupId == ProductGroup.Drinks && u.ProductStatus.Id == (int)ProductStatusEnum.Active);
```

I would like to have something like this:

```
  var product = await _context.Products.OrderBy(p => p.CreatedDate)
                .Select(x => new Product
                {
                    Title = x.Title,
                    Price = x.Price
                }).FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.ProductId == dbObj.Id && u.GroupId == ProductGroup.Drinks && u.ProductStatus.Id == (int)ProductStatusEnum.Active);
```

In classic (T-SQL) SQL statement I should be able to have columns in WHERE but NOT IN `SELECT` also, and here in `LINQ` looks like I must have columns in `SELECT` if I use them in `WHERE`.

Thanks

Cheers

Comment: @Sinatr Can I write this somehow so I could select only needed columns but leave firstordefault condition as it is. ? Thank for help

Comment: This is where you want to project into an anonymous class and then map to some type of model that only contains the columns you are interested in.

Comment: Just move the condition in the `FirstOrDefault` to a `Where` before the `Select`.

Comment: Instead of delegating the selection of what you want to show and want not to EF, I would suggest letting the View (or ViewModel in an MVVM app) decide what to show and what not

Answer (score 1):

Your query is not selecting columns, it's selecting new `Product` objects which you are setting the property values on. In the second case, you are only setting the `Title` and `Price` properties, and the others will be whatever the defaults are.

You may want to look at [anonymous types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types), e.g.:

```
.Select(x => new { Title = x.Title, Price = x.Price });
```

Comment: Can I write this somehow so I could select only needed columns but leave firstordefault condition as it is. ? Thank for help

Answer (score 1):

Just change the order of the Linq statements.  First filter by using `Where` before calling `Select` and use an anonymous object to project into:

```
var product = await _context.Products
                 .Where(u => u.ProductId == dbObj.Id 
                          && u.GroupId == ProductGroup.Drinks 
                          && u.ProductStatus.Id == (int) ProductStatusEnum.Active)
                 .OrderBy(p => p.CreatedDate)
                 .Select(x => new
                 {
                     Title = x.Title,
                     Price = x.Price
                 }).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

This creates an anonymous type (`product`) with 2 properties `Title` and `Price`.

---

If you don't want to use an anonymous type another option is to create a class which contains only the properties you want.

```
public class ProductSummary
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }                
}
```

Then you can select into the concrete class:

```
 .Select(x => new ProductSummary { Title = x.Title, Price = x.Price })
```

Comment: You should really do `Select(x => new Product {...})` to avoid having to deal with anonymous types

Comment: OP doesn't want the additional columns though, only wants the `Title` and `Price`. Selecting `new Product` will set all the other properties of `Product` to the default values @MindSwipe

Comment: @MindSwipe Projecting only some columns back to the original entity is a bad idea.  It will lead to confusion as to why some columns have the wrong data.  It's best to either hydrate the entire entity or map only the needed columns into a model, or just use anonymous classes if the data doesn't need to be passed out of the current method.

Comment: @juharr I agree, but I see one major flaw: You cannot return anonymous types. So when using this solution, the query needs to be executed where the data will be shown, as the anonymous objects will only be valid within the same context. IMO OP should just query for the entire object and let the View (or some layer between, like a ViewModel) decide what to show and what not to show, and not delegate that to EF

Comment: You can return anonymous types using `object` or `dynamic` @MindSwipe

Comment: Returning an `object` and casting it into a `dynamic` is throwing away one of the most powerful features of C#: It's type system, and isn't future-proof at all. Imagine you now want a query that returns the Title and the Time it was created and see this method and think "Ah, I don't need to return price, I want CreatedAt" and change it, only to find out that this breaks your app

Comment: It may be better to define some class like ProductLite or ProductDisplay, or whatever the name you find meaningful, to avoid dealing with anonymous objects (which works fine but may not be as "clear" than plain old class :-) )

Comment: @MindSwipe Like I said if the data needs to be passed out of the method that's when you should use a Model that has the specific data you need.